# How to reset bios on Toshiba L870?

Tags: bios, reset

I have a Toshiba Satellite L870 laptop and after change to CSM boot, the laptop has black screen. I will try to reset bios, but cannot find the cmos jumber, any ideas??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: remove power cord and battery, then remove the cmos battery for 30 seconds, re-insert it and power up then immediately enter the bios to set date and time.

Comment: Tried it a few time, but the same. Thanks!

Comment: So black screen before the bios loads? Try  leaving the battery out for 15 minutes, be sure no power cord or battery is attached,

Comment: Black screen all the time.Tried it, but no solved the issue.

Comment: Moabs suggestion is about as good as you can do.  You might need to leave the battery out longer than that.. try holding down the power button after everything is out to make sure it is drained.. otherwise.. I bet you are SOL.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. What is SOL?